# Dictionary performance improvement

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to improve on some code that was written a while back. the function is quite important to the core functionality of the system so I am cautious about a drastic overhaul.

I am using a dictionary to hold objects

```
Dictionary<Node, int> dConnections
```

The object `Node` is in itself a complex object containing many attributes and some lists.
This Dictionary could get quite large holding around 100 or more entries.

Currently the dictionary is being checked if it contains a node like

```
dConnections.ContainsKey(Node)
```

So I am presuming that (to check if this node is in the dictionary) the dictionary will have to check if the whole node and its attributes match a node in the dictionary (it will keep on iterating through the dictionary until it finds a match) and this will have a major impact on performance?

Would I be better off not using an object in the dictionary and rather use object id.

Comment: If I'm reading you ask "if the following code would improve performance drastically" but then only say how it is working currently... There isn't really a question here currently...

Comment: Sorry that's my bad, I should of wrote in the context of my program.

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of `Node` and it's `GetHashCode`?

Comment: I'm sure it works, but that Dictionary definition looks back to front. Usually you'd have the lightweight object as the key...

Comment: Sorry Tim I cant share the code.

Comment: @RobbieDee That's my concern. It looks like this may be the problem area

Comment: Basically the algorithm to calculate a unique hash key for the key object does depend on the complex type of the object. There are various parameters considered to calculate it. Check out Erric lipperts blog. I would suggest for a simple ID of the node or name which ever seem to be a unique than the object itself.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with a dictionary. Currently, everything shows it would be much better to just introduce a new property of type `int` in the `Node` class. Dictionaries and lookup data structures alike are meant as a mean to find a complex object by some kind of a simple key, and not vice-versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .NET dictionary is an hashtable in the Inside. It means that if Node doesn't overrides the GetHashCode and Equals methods, when you call ContainsKey, it will match against:

Disclaimer: It's a summary. Things are a little more complicated. Please don't call me name because I oversimplified.

1. a partition of the hashcode of the ref address of the Node object. The number of partitions dépends upon the number of buckets of the hashtable (depending on the total number of keys in the dictionnary)
2. the exact ref address if more than one Node is in the same bucket.

This algorithm is very efficient. When you say that you have 100 or more entries in the dictionary, it's not "a lot". It's a few.

It means also that the content of the Node object has nothing to do with the way a ContainsKey will match. It will match against the exact same reference, and only against this reference.

If you implement GetHashCode and Equals yourself, be aware that these method return values shouldn't change when the instance property change (be immutable). Otherwise you could well get keys in the wrong bucket, and therefore completely unreachable (without enumerating the whole dictionary).

Comment: Thanks, This has answered my question

Answer (score 3):

> it will keep on iterating through the dictionary until it finds a match

No, dictionaries don't find matches by iterating all nodes; the hash-code is obtained first, and is used to limit the candidates to one, maybe a few (depending on how good your hashing method is, and the bucket-size)

> So I am presuming that (to check if this node is in the dictionary) the dictionary will have to check if the whole node and its attributes match a node in the dictionary

No, for each candidate, it first checks the hash-code, which is intended to be a short-cut to detect **non**-equality vs *possible*-equality very quickly

So the key here is: your `Node`'s hashing method, aka `GetHashCode`. If this is complex, then another trick is to cache it the first time you need it, i.e.

```
int cachedHashCode;
public override int GetHashCode() {
    if(cachedHashCode == 0) {
       cachedHashCode = /* some complex code here */
       if(cachedHashCode == 0) {
           cachedHashCode = -45; // why not... just something non-zero
       }
    }
    return cachedHashCode;
}
```

Note that it *does* still use `Equals` too, as the final "are they the same", so you obviously want `Equals` to be as fast as possible too - but `Equals` will be called relatively rarely.

Comment: Thanks for this Mark, this explained allot.